# load TabPageIndicator when AsyncTask finish

Tags: android, android-asynctask, viewpagerindicator

I use the [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) library with a modifed version of `SampleTabsDefault.java`.

**What I want:**

I want to load some data in the background via `AsyncTask` and call `setAdapter` when the task finished.

**Problem:**

I receive the error: `ViewPager` has not been bound.

**Code:**

```
public class SampleTabsDefault extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Recent", "Artists",
            "Albums", "Songs", "Playlists", "Genres" };
    FragmentPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_tabs);
        new LoadContentTask().execute();
    }

    private void loadContent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(pager);
    }

    private class LoadContentTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg) {
            adapter = new GoogleMusicAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            return true;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            // process result
            loadContent();
        }
    }

    class GoogleMusicAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public GoogleMusicAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return CONTENT.length;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call setContentView when the task finished.